# Student Project Allocation in R

Tags: r, algorithm

Student rate their preferred project or topic on a scale from 1-3 or 1-5. I would like to assign as many as possible students to their best fit topic or project (maximize happiness).  Data might look like this (more students, more topics):

```
students <- data.frame(name = c("Fred", "Maria", "John"), 
                       Inequality = c("Weak", "Neutral", "Neutral"), 
                       Happiness = c("Strong", "Strong", "Neutral"),
                       Populism = c("Strong", "Weak", "Strong"))
```

I try to avoid a complex optimization problem. I would like to solve it in R. For simplicity, assume I have 1 topic per student (which I don't have).

```
    name Inequality Happiness Populism
1  Fred       Weak    Strong   Strong
2 Maria    Neutral    Strong     Weak
3  John    Neutral   Neutral   Strong
```

From looking at the table, I would give Inequality to Maria, Happiness to Fred and Populism to John (based on gut feeling for preference matching).

Is there any package that implements SPA or a similar algorithm? I found this github project https://github.com/richarddmorey/studentProjectAllocation but I am not able to install the package or start the Shiny App.

Comment: It would be better if you actually explain the problem to us, what exactly are you trying to solve with some data. I doubt many people know that specific script or how it works or why it might not work for you.

Comment: Any automation would improve manual assignment. I am fine with any algorithm.

Comment: What did you try? At first sight, this problem seems to involve only a lot of `if`-`else`-statements. By the way, why would you give Fred the Happiness topic if he has a similar strong preference for populism while Maria does not? I suggest you define some more criteria for your preferred algorithm (e.g. avoid allocation of "weak" topics or strive to fully satisfy strong preferences etc.).

Comment: I don't dare to specify an algorithm by myself. I was hoping to find several different implementations in R, but obviously that's not the case. I found a perfect plugin for moodle: https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_ratingallocate It pretty much describes what I would like to do (in R).